# Apache log analyzer that can handle URL parameters?

Tags: apache, url, logging, analysis, query-string

I have a web site that uses IBM Websphere Portal technology with an Apache web server inside.  The content for the web site is stored in Oracle's UCM (the web content management system).

When a user of the web site asks for a web page, a request like this is logged in the Apache log

10.32.3.111 - - [26/Jun/2010:11:16:09 +1000] "GET /wps/myportal/[site]/[site-section]/?CDF=xxxx HTTP/1.1"

where ?CDF=xxxx are URL parameters telling the web content management system which content page to get.

The web analysis/reporting tool I am using (Sawmill) does not seem to understand the URL parameters and reports a lot of 'hits' on the URL at the [site]/[site-section] level i.e. its not recognising hits on pages in that section of the site, just that the request was for something in that section.

Im looking for a web log analyzer/reporting tool that can:

- understand the parameters and report on 'hits' for specific content pages under the [site-section] e.g  maybe Sawmill or similar can be configured to understand the URL parameters,  or
- a way to convert what is recorded in the logs so that a normal web log analyzer/reporting tool can understand it.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Query parameters can get out of control quickly. Do you want to limit the parameter names that show up in the reports? Angelfish Software does this.  http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

You can [check out a demo at this link](http://www.nltechno.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=destailleur.fr)

Though the demo does not show it - specifically you can enable the querystrings to be tracked separately by setting

```
URLWithQuery=1
```

Comment: Thanks JoseK, I came across AWStats as well.  Do you know if it can be used to analyse an existing log file without having to install AWStats on a web server?  I have a log file from another server and just want to see what AWStats would produce given that log file.

Comment: @Fortilan: think you can do so. http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_setup.html#BUILD_UPDATE shows it can be used to read an offline file and output a report into an HTML file. it runs as a perl command so you need ActivePerl or similar installed.